# Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost

Tags: spring-boot, memory-leaks, database-connection, amazon-aurora, hikaricp

I have migrated my database connection to Aurora MySQL in AWS, my application written in spring boot. After migration i am facing

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

this issue continuously, I have made some changes to application.properties file and added the HikariPool dependency in the

pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
        <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout = 40000
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle= 10
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=10000
spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime= 1000
spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit =true
```

and used this as spring datasource

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://xxxxxxxxxxxxx:3306/database_name?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
```

Exception log

```
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:827)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:447)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:237)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:199)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:136)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:369)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:198)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:467)
at com.zaxx
```

I am not getting where i am doing wrong.